# Use Hooks within class that doesn't doesn't get rendered

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a child class that returns some JSX (an ion-item) it uses a hook to control some ion-icons (using the hook like a state but only because I can use useEffect which is very handy).

I also have a Bluetooth class. This is home to all the important Bluetooth functions. The reason it is in its own class is because I need this code accessible everywhere in the app (including the list of devices (the ion-items mentioned above) it creates).
I do it like this:

```js
const _Bluetooth = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        addDevice();
    }, [state]);

    const devices: any[] = [];

    const bluetoothInitialize = () => {

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            let a = {name: "test", mac: i.toString(), connected:false}
            setState({found: [...state.found, a]});
        }
    }

    const connect = (id) => {
        console.log("connecting");
    }

    const addDevice = () => {
        let d = state.found[state.found.length - 1]
        devices.push(<BluetoothDeviceItem key={d.mac} mac={d.mac} name={d.name} onClick={(id) => connect(id)} connectingState={d.connected ? 'connected' : 'not_connected'}></BluetoothDeviceItem>);
    }

    return {
        devices, bluetoothInitialize, connect
    };
}

export default _Bluetooth;
```

I then create an instance of this class in another file which acts as a global file and then other files import this global file giving access to that one instance of the class:

```js
import _Bluetooth from '../components/bluetooth/Bluetooth'

export const Bluetooth = _Bluetooth();
```

Unfortunately the _Bluetooth class doesn't work. Since I am using a hook, React expects the component to be rendered and therefore the component needs to return JSX. However I don't want it to return JSX but rather the accessible functions and variables.
Like I said above I am using these hooks more like states but only because of the useEffect function.
I could easily get this working by doing:

```js
const state = {found: []}
```

and then directly pushing items to the array. This takes away my ability of using useEffect which makes my life a little bit easier but also cleans up the code a little bit.

Is it possible to use hooks without rendering the components / returning any JSX?

Comment: You will have to return jsx. So why not just expose a prop ( maybe call it `getState` ) that you can call on the parent, or even better use the `context` to expose a `getState` method. and then just return null or an empty div or something?

Comment: Hooks can only be called during component render. You can `return null` to render nothing.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I did have something similar a while ago but I scrapped it because it would return the state but "a bit behind" so if the state was 'not_connected' and then on click it was set to 'connecting' it would still return 'not_connected' until the the device was clicked on for a *second* time.

Comment: @UjinT34 I can't test it right now but do you mean just adding null to the list like this:
`return ( [null, devices, bluetoothInitialize, connect] );`

Comment: That sounds like an issue with how you define your callback. It should be able to reference the current state values. I'd use context here though, its a good way to handle this sort of thing

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks for the suggestion of context. I'll have a play around with it to see what I can get done.